# Pandas background_gradient only for values above a given threshold

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
# using apply
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Values A":[1,2,3,4,5], "Values B":[0,11,12,13,15]})

df.style.background_gradient(subset = "Values B")
```

However this code changes the color of all cells in column `Values B`. I would like to change the color only for cells which values for example are bigger than 11, so 12,13, 15. How can I do that? Adding `vmin = 11` didnt solve my problem beacuse the color of cells below 11 is still changed.

[image]

Comment: *beacuse the color of cells below 11 is still changed*...Isn't that what you want for values above 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just subset rows, as well as you do columns.

```py
df.style.background_gradient(subset=(df["Values B"]>11, "Values B"))
```

Use greater than or equal to 11 if necessary.

[image]